# C++ thread safe vector insertion

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, c++14, c++17

Multiple threads process data and at the end they all insert/append results in RESULT vector.
I want to make sure that only one thread insert elements in RESULT vector at a time.
For that I have used mutex and lock_guard() but they are giving invalid access error sometimes and sometimes they don't...
Here is my code to synchronize

```
void insert_output() {
    mutex m;
    lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(m);
    Resources::results.insert(Resources::results.begin(), output.begin(), output.end());
}
```

Am I doing something wrong...
And what is better way to synchronize this process ?

Comment: Also, side note: Inserting at the *beginning* of a `std::vector` *always* requires copying/moving the whole vector. That will take a long time very quickly. You should insert only at the *end* of a `std::vector`. If you need insertion at the beginning, use `std::deque` or `std::list` or insert at the end in reverse and reverse the vector afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be only *one* mutex for the vector. So you should add the mutex next to the vector, e.g. as `results_mutex` in `Resources`. If `results` is a static member then the mutex should be a static member as well (so that there is only one mutex for the vector).

Then you must also lock the mutex on all operations accessing the vector that could potentially be executed in parallel with a call to `insert_output`, not *only* on the insert operation.

In your current code you create a new mutex on each call, making it completely pointless.

Comment: insertion is the only place where any thread use results vector... all thread have their own output result to store temporary results and once they are done, they insert output in main shared results vector. So, I am making sure that results vector is getting used at a single place only...  I want to ask that should I declare that mutex as static variable to make sure it gets shared between all thread as I am doing with main results vector.

Comment: @xyzxyz If that is the case you can simply declare `m` as `static` or as global outside the function and be done with it, yes, but that is not a clean solution. It works only because `results` is a static variable and wouldn't work correctly if it was a non-static member. It also is easier to reason about the code if the mutex is directly paired with the object it is guarding.

Comment: Hey, Should I put lock_guard in resource class too... as a static member?

Comment: @xyzxyz No, the `lock_guard` always should be an automatic variable in the block in which you intend to access the guarded object (and declared before the actual access). If there were multiple such places, you would use multiple `lock_guard`s, but still only one mutex.

Answer (score 2):

With a slight enhancement to the specification, this becomes quite simple. If you have `n` threads that each create `m` results, just create your vector with `n*m` elements and have each thread copy its results into an appropriate subrange. So thread `j` copies its results to `results[j*m]` through `results[j*m + m - 1]`. No synchronization needed, since none of the threads are simultaneously modifying the same element.

More generally, if you know in advance how many results each thread will create, you can tile the result vector appropriately so that there are no conflicting writes.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make the mutex to one instance,
it makes a lock per instance.

```cpp
mutex m;
void insert_output() {
    lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(m);
    Resources::results.insert(Resources::results.begin(), output.begin(), output.end());
}
```

Comment: Okay that's good, but the next question is    
should I declare mutex m as a static variable because as you said  "make the mutex to one instance" to avoid  "a lock per instance"?